# when to call removeObserver for nsnotificationcenter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications, nsnotification

I have a view controller with a button action:

```
@IBAction func MultiplayerButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
              self, 
              selector: NotificationConstants.pvpConnEstablishedSelector, 
              name: NotificationConstants.pvpConnEstablishedString , 
              object: nil)

            setUpGameScene()
            initiateMultiplayerGC()
    }
```

and somewhere, a notification is posted that triggers the selector for this observer:

```
//action for pvpConnEstablishedSelector
func hideMainView() {
   MenuView.hidden = true
   //NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self) ???
}
```

is it a good place to call `removeObserver` in the function that is the selector for the observer?

or is there a more suitable place to do this?

Comment: At what point do you no longer need to receive notifications? If after you receive the first notification, you no longer need any additional notifications, then sure, remove your observer there.

Comment: Obviously if you remove it in the observer function then you will not receive any more notifications. You don't state if you only want to receive the first notification or not therefore it is impossible to comment on if its a "good" place to call removeObserver or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. I infer from your code comment that you are contemplating removing the observer inside the selector for that particular notification. That is a fine practice.

   I'd be wary about just calling `removeObserver`, though, because that will remove all observers that you may have set up. If you are calling this inside the routine that is the selector for a particular notification, then I might be inclined to remove only that particular notification:

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: NotificationConstants.pvpConnEstablishedString, object: nil)
   ```

   Yes, at this point, you may only be observing a single notification, so this may feel unnecessary, but if at some future date you add completely separate notification handling code for a different notification, you want to make sure that you don't accidentally remove all observers when handling a particular notification.
2. You might want to be sensitive to the possibility that this view controller may be dismissed before the notification comes in. In that case, it might be prudent to also add `removeObserver` in the `deinit` method for the view controller.

   In this case, the simple `removeObserver(self)` is prudent (because it's reasonable to remove all observers when the view controller is deallocated).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, you want to be sensible on what you are removing and when you are removing it... However you may want to add the following to the class that is observing such notification with the following:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

replace self with the name of the notification as mentioned before that you want to remove specifically. This will remove when your class has been uninstantiated and its ready for garbage collection.

[Here](http://natashatherobot.com/ios8-where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification-in-swift/) you may find a whole discussion on this subject and maybe you can form an opinion of your own on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

You no longer need to removeobserver from ios9+. It removes itself automatically.

[enter link description here](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/)